# POS for .NET - MSR device not attached but found, opened, and claimed successfully

Tags: .net, opos

I have the following code that looks for MSR devices using POS for .NET, and returns an instance that matches my device name. Then I open and claim the instance that is found successfully even though the MSR device is not attached to the computer. How come this is possible? Is there a way to know if the device is trully attached before opening and claiming it? I don't get an exception or anything upon calling Open() or Claim() when the device is not attached. Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

```
PosExplorer explorer = new PosExplorer();
            var devices = explorer.GetDevices(DeviceType.Msr);
            foreach (DeviceInfo deviceInfo in devices)
            {
                if (deviceInfo.ServiceObjectName.ToLower() == deviceName.ToLower())
                {
                    PosDevice posDevice = explorer.CreateInstance(deviceInfo);
                    if (posDevice is PosCommon)
                    {
                        posCommon = posDevice as PosCommon;
                        _log.Debug(string.Format("Instance of device {0} created.", deviceName));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the device supports power reporting, you can check `StatusPowerOff` to see if the device is powered off or attached to the terminal (see [Microsoft Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.pointofservice.poscommon.statuspoweroff%28v=winembedded.11%29.aspx))

> PosCommon.StatusPowerOff : Indicates that the device’s power is turned off or it is detached from the terminal.

You would also need to check `CapPowerReporting` first to see if the device supports power reporting or not.

There is also the following that may help (from the [MSR Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.pointofservice.msr_members%28v=winembedded.11%29.aspx))

- `StatusPowerOffline` : Indicates that the device is powered on but is either not ready or unable to respond to requests
- `StatusPowerOffOffline` : Indicates that either the device’s power is off or it is offline
- `StatusPowerOnline` : Indicates that the device’s power is turned on and it is ready for use.